# Will a previous visa rejection affect my Canadian visa application?

Tags: visas, canada, australia, pakistan

I wish to apply for a Canadian visit visa. I will be applying from Pakistan. I will be visiting a friend so I have some questions.

1. I am still a student, 22 years old. Will that affect its outcome?
2. Can my friend sponsor me?
3. I have a traveling history to Saudi Arabia (almost 6 times) and Malaysia, one time. Is that a weak history?
4. I have been denied an Australian visa twice due poor socioeconomic conditions of the country; failure to show good home ties. Will that affect the Canadian visa application outcome?
5. Since I am still studying, I don't own any land. All I can show them is a bonafide from my university as a proof to return back. Will that suffice?

Comment: What is your friend’s immigration status in Canada?

Comment: Have your circumstances improved since your failed applications to Australia? If your application is equally weak, it is likely Canada will reject for the same reason.

Comment: How do i improve the circumstances of my country? And how to make a stronger application than before ? Also my friend holds a PR there.

Comment: @Sidra If the only tie you have to your home country is being enrolled at university there, and that hasn’t changed since your previous refusals, it’s likely you’ll be refused this time too. Strong home ties usually include a job, savings, family members. A strong travel history typically includes visits to countries of equivalent standing to Canada eg USA, Schengen countries, Australia.

Comment: @Traveller alright, apart from the enrollment, family registration certificate, what else do i include to show  stronger home ties? Since i am still a student and don't have any job, can't show any savings etc. I am planning a trip to Latvia ( one of the Schengen countries ) as they have good acceptance rate as opposed to other Schengen countries. Your thoughts on that?

Comment: @Sidra This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy might help

Answer (score 1):

Numerous factors are weighed in the visa decision making process, and no one can predict the outcome of a visa application to Canada.

Some of your circumstances are not particularly favorable, that you are a student and may not have sufficient financial resources or home ties;  travel history and university enrollment may be positives.

A friend’s sponsorship, if it is financial, may not improve the picture a great deal; a invitation offering to accommodate and feed you might be useful.

Your application to Canada will have to include information about the Australia refusals. If your situation has not improved, the Canadian process, while not based on those failed applications, may have a similar result.

To identify what steps to take, use the [Come to Canada tool](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/come-canada-tool.html). It will let you know what you would be expected to provide to support an application.

Although not about Canada, have a read of these similar questions and answers on home ties and sponsorship:

[How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

[What should a sponsor tell the ECO?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco)

[How can I document my relation to a friend for the purposes of Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73828/how-can-i-document-my-relation-to-a-friend-for-the-purposes-of-schengen-visa/73887#73887)