# Why didn't I get Schengen refusal stamp on my passport?

Tags: visa-refusals, passport-stamps, schengen-visas

My Visa request for Schengen Visa has been refused by German embassy in Tehran[[1]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73726/re-interviewed-for-schengen-visa-but-got-rejected-for-other-reasons). I've got the refusal notice explaining the reasons for the refusal. But I don't find any stamp on my passport. Is that normal or they've forgot it?

Comment: My understanding is that they stamp your passport if you are refused entry, but not if a visa application is refused.

Comment: What is the difference?  @phoog

Comment: In the first case, you either have a visa, or you don't need one because you're from an "annex ii" country, and when you show up at the border they decide not to let you in.  In the second case, you're in the situation that you are now actually in.

Comment: i think your passport only gets stamped if the visa application is accepted and the visa issued

Comment: @Newton actually if the application is accepted, they put a sticker in the passport, not a stamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessary to have a refusal stamp in your passport.

The fact of your visa refusal will be recorded in the [Schengen Information System](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system/index_en.htm), and the information will be available to the consulates and border officers of all Schengen countries. The same reasons for refusal that are ticked on your refusal notice are also recorded.

Thus, all Schengen states will be aware that you have had a previous visa refusal from Germany, and the reasons for the refusal that the consulate gave to you.

Comment: How long does it stay on Schengen Information System? @michael-hampton

Comment: @Jamaisavenir The information will stay for a minimum of three years, and the country which issued the alert can extend the duration if necessary.

Comment: @Jamaisavenir this answer isn't quite correct; information on visa refusals is to be entered into the [Visa Information System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en), not the SIS (see Art. 32 of the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412)).  An SIS alert would not be necessary for most visa refusals.